# Getting error in handling the selected row in table in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchTableViewCellIdentifier") as! SearchTableViewCell
    var item = self.searchResult[indexPath.row] as? PFObject

    cell.post = item


    return cell
}
```

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int)
    {

```
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

    println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
}
```

I am not getting the actual value. I am getting nil on printing currentCell.textLabel!.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove `override`

```
class yourclassName: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate


var cod: AnyObject?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int)
{

//Handle row selection

   // choice 1
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

  // if it is not work follow second option
   cod = self.searchResult[indexPath.row] as? PFObject

    // choice 2
   cod = self.searchResult[rowIndex] as? PFObject



    println(cod)



   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueName", sender: self)
 }


  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueName") {
var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;

svc.toPass = cod

}
}
```

in your second VC create this string

```
  var toPass:String!
```

Comment: thanks error is removed but it is not working. on selecting any this method is not getting hit.

Comment: it is printing nil for println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)

Comment: I the cell which i an using in table view containing three lable

Comment: @hatim -- this is the customize answer u need the exact answer , show your cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: 'func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchTableViewCellIdentifier") as! SearchTableViewCell
        var item = self.searchResult[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
        
        cell.post = item
        
        
        return cell
    }
'

Comment: @hatim -- it means you got the answer , correct , now we need to customize the answer .. correct , just update your question

Comment: no i got nil. but there exist text in the cell which i have selected